# Any 3rd party Table like controls for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I know about Grid. What I don't like about Grid is that I have to specifically index every single row and col. So afterwards, if I want to just move one row or col, I have to go update a ton of xaml.

I tried stackpanel and styles but then even this is a lot of redundant xaml and rearanging the screen still involves then removing/updating styles.

I really like how in an html table, I just start laying out my rows and cols on the fly. If I want to move a row, that's easy, I can just copy paste the xaml to the right spot, nothing else needs to get touched. A col, is a bit harder, but still can be done easily with cut/paste, just needs to be done to every row.

With grid, one may need to touch every single thing in it depending on what's moved.

And what would be really cool, is if one could declare the column width and row heights up above just like a grid. But then as need, provide override values in the actual row,col declaration down below that actually contains the gui elements.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen implementation of a Grid that infers ColumnDefinitions from usage of attached properties.  Its definately doable.  You could create an attached property that signifies that this element is the last element of a row.
(See WrapBreakPanel in Pro Silverlight 4 in C# By Matthew MacDonald)

> And what would be really cool, is if one could declare the column
>   width and row heights up above just like a grid. But then as need,
>   provide override values in the actual row,col declaration down below
>   that actually contains the gui elements.

Sounds like this could get confusing.  What if multiple cells in a row override the height?  You can pull this off already with Auto sizing a row and having elements take up more space as needed.

Comment: What I was getting at is that many times in html, either I'll have a 0 pixel high empty first row just to set all the column widths or I set the column widths in the real first row (if there's no spans).